# Exchange Server - automatically change an address from the To field to the BCC

Tags: email, exchange

We have an ALL distribution list (DL), which obviously includes all of our users.
Sometimes, when someone is sending an email to ALL, a thread begins which includes the ALL DL. We don't like it.

W'd like the Exchange Server to automatically rip that DL from the To field and move it to the BCC field.

We can use any Exchange Server that support this feature.

Comment: The typical approach is to genuinely secure such an enterprise wide mailing list and either restrict access to a small number of trusted senders or appoint a moderator, rather than an obfuscation approach...

Comment: @HBruijn, I don't see the reason to unvote. Restrict access is not my decision. Currently, managers ask users to manually send using the BCC field. I need an automatic solution to this request. This is not an obfuscation approach. "You can send to ALL. Restrictions apply."

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, I just gave an opinion on an alternative and more common approach that prevents the most typical concern you appeared to try and address: that users respond to a company wide announcement with a reply-all and then they annoy everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange cannot do this on its own.
The only method I can think of would be to use a third party tool that does header rewriting. While Edge can do header rewriting, that is too late for you, so it would have to be something running on your internal Hub Transport role servers.